# Essential Grid Facebook Share

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook

Essential Grid has an option to create a link to Share on Facebook, however when i try to put it, on the front end the link appears with **javascript: void(0)**.
What can be the problem?

Also, is it possible to do with custom URL something like:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{postURL}}
I can do that in Revolution Slider but i dont know how to get the post URL in Essential Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround!

add this link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%post_url%" target="_blank"><i class="eg-icon-facebook-1"></i></a>
```

Here:
[image]

Source:https://www.themepunch.com/faq/social-sharing-alternative-2/